# Word2vec is a Generalization or memorization algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec, knn

I need to know that word2vec is a Generalization algorithm like all ML algorithms or its Memorization algorithm like KNN ?
Because we have 2 types of algorithms model based and memory based , word2vec is coming in which category when it's using for most_similar_items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me define generalization as the ability of a model which has completed training to be effective in prediction across a whole range of inputs, including include inputs that is not part of training. From that perspective, Word2Vec cannot predict words that are not part of the training dataset because it simply would not have trained on the context of it to create an embedding. To qualify as a generalization method, it needs to be able to predict on an input which was not part of the training dataset.

Word2Vec model maintains a dictionary of words to the corresponding embedding/vector. In summary, cannot predict on unknown words. This was one of the important differences between fastText model and Word2Vec.

Comment: So FastText model it also memorize the dictionary and predicts similarity based on dictionary like word2vec or it is a generalization model which don't hold the dictionary to predict the similar words/articles/movies

Comment: Actually I'm finding a method to train a model to predict the similar movies based on its description/keywords but i don't want any model to hold the dictionary in RAM to predict the similar items but I'm newbie to ML and don't know what should i do

Comment: Pease answer both comments of mine seprately i need it

Comment: @HassanAbbas : So, fastText stores character n-grams and has word embeddings based on those. Word2Vec has embeddings per word. fastText can use vector addition to derive the word embedding corresponding to a word by adding the appropriate character n-gram embeddings. Word2Vec cannot derive the embedding for an unseen word because it does not store character n-gram embeddings. Further, for word ngrams, word2vec can derive the embeddings by the same vector addition strategy

Comment: @HassanAbbas To your second question, this can go in a lot of different directions. You could extract top keywords in the description using a keyword extraction algorithm, then convert them to word embeddings and then do clustering or other similar approaches. There could be some value that you derive by looking at https://github.com/cemoody/lda2vec